# Why are handler functions listed with arguments in the jQuery API documentation?

Tags: jquery, syntax

In the jQuery manual itself it shows the [**blur**](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) function as:

```
.blur(handler(eventObject)) // PLUS 2 OTHER VARIATIONS
```

So to me using this function you would get something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1" />
      <input type="text" value="Field 2" />
    </form>
    <div id="other">Trigger the handler</div>
    <script>
      $('#target').blur(myhandler(evObj));

      function myhandler(evObj) {
        console.log(evObj);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But `$('#target').blur(myhandler(evObj));` is not the correct syntax the correct syntax is really `$('#target').blur(myhandler);`

So overall the entire code for script tag should be:

```
<script>
  $('#target').blur(myhandler);

  function myhandler(e) {
    console.log(e);
  };
</script>
```

1. Why is this so?
2. How is someone supposed to know NOT to write `.blur(handler(eventObject))`  ?

Comment: You use the functionname() if you want to make use of the returned value. In this case, you don't.

Comment: wrong docs. http://docs.jquery.com/Events/blur

Comment: oh i see what you mean it doesn't excplicitly say it passes it. fair question

Comment: Learning javascript basics before trying to make yetanothercoolappwithjquery would help a lot. ;)

Comment: I found myself in this situation in the past and realised that learning JavaScript through jQuery was the wrong aproach and if I wanted to understand jQuery properly I needed to learn JavaScript first. I found [Mozilla Developer Documentation on Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) extremly good for start. It answered a lot of question about behaviours which I thought were odd in jQuery but now make sense as that is how JavaScript works.

Comment: Francois  I found the answer at http://www.learnjavascript.co.uk/jq/reference/events/blur.html before I posted the question, but I posted anyways. I didn't 'see' the answer at http://api.jquery.com/blur/ . I just wondered how others arrive at the correct answer from mimimal docs at jquery.com, and understand 'oh thats what they mean' which I don't get just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are just another kind of object. You've stumbled upon the big difference between writing `myfunction` and `myfunction()` -- the first is the function object, the second is the return value of that function.

So: `$('#target').blur(...)` is a method that accepts one object, which **must** be a function.

When you write `$('#target').blur( myhandler(evObj) )`, then the `myhandler` *function* is not passed to `.blur()`. Instead, the parentheses that follow it tell JavaScript to evaluate the function (using the argument `evObj`), and the function's *return value* is passed to `.blur()` instead.

If that return value happens to be another function object, then all is good. But if not, you'll get an error.

Usually, however, developers won't declare a separate function `myhandler`. Instead, we'll use an *anonymous function* like so:

```
$('#target').blur(function(evObj) {
    /* do stuff with evObj */
})
```

**That's** why the API docs write `$('#target').blur( myhandler(evObj) )` -- so developers know what arguments are accepted by the anonymous handler function.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the technically-correct syntax would be

```
blur(handler)
```

However, this isn't actually very useful, because if you're looking at the docs you probably want to know what arguments the handler receives. It's meant to be obvious that you call `blur` with a *function* as its sole argument, so the jQuery docs *par abus de notation* write

```
blur(handler(eventObj))
```

to indicate that the handler function takes one argument, the event object.